# How to access @ConfigurationProperties bean by it's name from XML configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have an `AppProperties` POJO annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("app")`. It contains different app properties which I usually use to configure my beans in `@Configuration` classes. 
`@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)` makes it available for `@Autowiring`, this is very convenient for Java-configuration.

But one part of my app's context is configured using old-fashined XML-confiuration. I would like to know how can I access `@ConfigurationProperties AppProperties` bean in XML configuration? If only `@EnableConfigurationProperties` provided me an ability to give a `name`, I could probably use SpEL in XML like this: `#{appProperties.requiredProp}` (I would really like to achieve it).

Unfortunately I do not see a way to provide the name and my attempt to use suggested `appProperties` name fails with:

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'appProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

I've seen in debugger that the bean is actually called `app-my.package.AppProperties` which is not obvious and never stated explicitly.

In JavaDoc for `@EnableConfigurationProperties` I noticed the following:

> `@ConfigurationProperties` beans can be registered in the standard way (for example using `@Bean` methods) or, for convenience, can be specified directly on this (`@EnableConfigurationProperties`) annotation.

Does this mean I can somehow get a named instance of `AppProperties` with values injected from `application.properties` using either `@Bean` method in Java or `<bean/>` in XML?

Of course, I could autowire the whole `AppProperties` to the class configured with XML, but I do not think it is a good design solution, because am only interested in a single `String` property from `AppProperties`. Probably I should not try to use this "type-safe" properties manner in XML and just stick to old way: using `${}`-resolution, but I feel like I am missing something in the `@ConfigurationProperties` concept so please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to register a configuration properties bean.

Registering with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

```
 @EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
 public class Application {}

 @ConfigurationProperties("app")
 public class AppProperties {}
```

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation will automatically register `AppProperties` class as a bean called `prefix-your.package.AppProperties`, when you include the class as follows: `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)` and `AppProperties` has got a prefix, `@ConfigurationProperties("app")`.

Registering with `@Component` or `@Bean`

```
 @EnableConfigurationProperties
 public class Application {}

 @Component
 @ConfigurationProperties("app")
 public class AppProperties {}
```

or

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app")
    public AppProperties appProperties() {
        return new AppProperties();
    }

}
```

The `@Component` and `@Bean` will register a bean called `appProperties`.
By using the second approach you would be able to use SpEL to get the property `#{appProperties.requiredProp}`